# Ansible: Replace word in file

Tags: python, ansible

I'm making a Ansible playbook to setup CSF.
I've got everything done except for the last part.

I'd like to disable port 22 in the `/etc/csf/csf.conf` file.
So `TCP_OUT = "20,21,22,25,53,80,110,113,443,587,993,995"` needs `22` removed.
I don't want to replace the entire line as some lines are different, some got port `2087` open, or `2222` for example.
Is there any way I can only filter on `22`?

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several options:

- [shell](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/shell_module.html) module with sed
- [lineinfile](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/lineinfile_module.html) module
- [replace](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/replace_module.html) module

This solution uses [replace](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/replace_module.html) module, to look for a line beginning with `TCP_OUT =` and replace `,22,` with `,` in the line.

```
  tasks:
  - name: Strip port 22
    replace:
      dest: /etc/csf/csf.conf
      regexp: '^TCP_OUT\s*=\s*(.*),22,(.*)$'
      replace: 'TCP_OUT = \1,\2'
```

- **\s*** - Matches zero or more white spaces (blanks, tabs etc.,)
- **\1** - Whatever matched in the first group (.*)
- **\2** - Whatever matched in the second group (.*)

Comment: Ah perfect. Would you mind, if it's not too much to ask to break it down? 
I know `\s` is a whiteline,`^` begin and `$` end...

What exactly makes sure it matches on BOTH, not either? the `=`?

Answer (score 1):

Code working proof

```
>>> TCP_OUT = '20,21,22,25,53,80,110,113,443,587,993,995,2087,2222,22'
>>> print(','.join([port for port in TCP_OUT.split(',') if port != '22']))
'20,21,25,53,80,110,113,443,587,993,995,2087,2222'
```

Comment: The default config is `"20,21,22,25,53,80,110,113,443,587,993,995"`, but a cPanel server would have 2087 in it. 
Doing it 'your way' would mean I'd have to open port 2222 and 2087 on all servers, non-directadmin and cPanel servers as well?

Comment: Oh i see, I think I can add some file reading code & also a check to do the replace on the line containing the string "TCP_OUT = ". That sounds good?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [template](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/template_module.html).  Make a copy of your `/etc/csf/csf.conf` file and for the TCP_OUT line replace it with an ansible variable:

```
TCP_OUT = {{ port_list }}
```

Then set the list ahead of time in a variable with the ports you desire in the file.

```
vars:
  port_list = "20,21,25,53,80,110,113,443,587,993,995"
```

Comment: If all servers would be the same, that'd be perfect, but as mentioned I have cPanel and DirectAdmin servers as well..
Wouldn't make much sense in having several different playbooks?